# Fastest Search algorithm in 2D array

Tags: c, algorithm, search

So, I have a 2D array, `int a[X][Y];`
`X` can go up to *10 000 000* and `Y` is maximum *6*.
Given an array `int v[Z]` (*Z <= Y*), I have to see if I find a line in a that contains all the elements from `v`.

What would be the fastest algorithm for this matter and how would you implement this?

I have already tried the classic method of taking line by line and then with the 2 fors search, one for v elements and one for a elements but it takes too long.

What would be the best (fastest) approach ?

```
int check()
{
    int nrfound;

    for (int l = 0; l < lines_counter; l++) for each line in a array
    {
        nrfound = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // for each element in v array

            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) // for each element in a[l] line
                if (v[i] == a[l][j])
                    nrfound++;
            if (nrfound == Z)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Formally the best one would be `O(X*Y)`. The one you implemented is the same complexity, so asymptotically you have the best.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Are you thinking of `a[X] == v`? Because the question appears to be asking for whether `a[X]` is a superset of `v`...

Comment: You can try using `memcmp(a[i], v, sizeof(v))` and see if that speeds things up. If it doesn't, your out of luck: You already have the fastest implementation possible.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Oh, I see. Worse than `O(XY)` then. `O(XY log Y)` is what I can think of.

Comment: @cmaster, not necessarily true, and `sizeof(v)` is dangerous because `v` might be a pointer.

Comment: Also you can split work for few threads.

Comment: You should post your code, perhaps there are some microoptimizations that would help a lot and you have missed them. It often happens when you have little experience.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi True. In that case, one would need to replace `sizeof(v)` with `Z*sizeof(*v)`.

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that I have 100 000 combinations for v array, and I need to do this check for each of them. So 100 000 combinations * time / combination  = many hours. That's why I would need a better approach, if there is one.

Comment: 100 000 **many** hours is a lot, please post your code.

Comment: "fastest algorithm " --> worst case, or on  average with wide `int range?

Comment: I immediately see an improvement, instead of counting if the number of values is equal, abort on the first non equal value.

Comment: There's a bug in the code as written... if `v = {1, 2, 3}` and `a[l] = {1, 1, 1, 4}`, it will count as a match. If `a[l] = {1, 2, 3, 3}`, it will not count as a match.

Comment: Would be even better if code compiled.  `lines_counter, m, n, v, a, Z` missing.

Comment: If the product of the `y` elements < 64-bit, then it can be used against each `a[]` using `%` as a quick pre-filter.

Comment: Are you going to use the same array a[] with multiple different v[]?

Comment: If you are performing many searches on the same set of data it might be worth sorting the list first.  That way you can perform a quicker search, either binary chopping the data or doing something cleverer if you know enough about how the data is distributed.

Comment: @MBo yes, that is my intention

Comment: so given this, what would be the best sorting method for a[N][M] array? N = 100 000 000, M = 6. What would be the fastest algorithm for sorting this array? ( I need the elements of each line to stay together )

Implementation in C would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I see three things to consider:

- Using threads.
- If it's possible, when constructing `int a[X][Y]` table I would create additional array `int[6][Y]` which will contain:

  - List of indexes which contain 1, 2, 3 .. 6 elements. This allows you to narrow the search.
- For each X count Hash of it's values. Then count Hash of V values.

  - Compare Hash code, instead of each separate value.

Comment: so given this, what would be the best sorting method for a[N][M] array? N = 100 000 000, M = 6. What would be the fastest algorithm for sorting this array? ( I need the elements of each line to stay together )

Implementation in C would be great.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of reusing the same array a[] with multiple different v[]:

Sort every line of a[][] as preliminary step (executed once)

Sort v[]

Use single loop (instead of two) to get intersection of ordered v[] and every ordered line of a[]  - with approach like `merge` procedure of merge sort

```
index_v = 0
index_a = 0
while index_v < length_v and index_a < length_a:
   if v[index_v] == a[index_a]
       index_v++, index_a++
   else if v[index_v] < a[index_a]
       index_v++   
   else
     index_a++
if index_v == length_v:
   return OK, a[] line contains all v elements
```

Comment: so given this, what would be the best sorting method for a[N][M] array? N = 100 000 000, M = 6. What would be the fastest algorithm for sorting this array? ( I need the elements of each line to stay together )

Implementation in C would be great.

Comment: To sort lines with length=6? Any method, for example - insertion sort. There are special methods for concrete length, but they are more complex and would not give significant gain.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting 1e7 arrays of size 6 can be easily parallelized using fixed sorting network with or without Simd/multithreading.

Sort `v` and compare that with same principle as merge sorting two sorted lists.

The overall worst case complexity is between 13e7..24e7 comparisons (sorting network for 6 elements requires 12 conditional swaps and merging v/a[n] requires 1..12 comparisons.

Comment: could you detail the algorithm for fixed sorting network and for the comparison with the principle of merge sorting two sorted lists ? :D

Comment: so given this, what would be the best sorting method for a[N][M] array? N = 100 000 000, M = 6. What would be the fastest algorithm for sorting this array? ( I need the elements of each line to stay together )

Implementation in C would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has a flaw if there are duplicate elements in the `a[i][]` subarrays.  A matching element of `v` will be counted multiple times and the count may equal `Z` by coincidence.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int check(int X, int Y, int Z, int a[X][Y], int v[Z]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < X; x++) {
        // for each line in array a
        int mask = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < Z; z++) {
            // for each element in array v
            for (int y = 0, m = 1; y < Y; y++, m <<= 1) {
                // for each element in line a[x]
                if (v[z] == a[x][y] && !(mask & m)) {
                    mask |= m;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (y == Y)
                break;
        }
        if (z == Z)
            return 0;   // found a match
        }
    }
    return 1;   // no match
}
```

Unfortunately, the above code might be even slower than the posted one, but it is worth testing as the inner loop is exited as soon as a element from `v` is not found in `a[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

As you're working in C, it limits available data structures:
I would suggest :

- Initialize N threads, divide matrix rows X in N buckets, and run searching for each bucket in parallel.
- Depending on type of 2D input array : You can save some time with boundary conditions as you want all elements of query array maintain the order. You can also make use of (Z <= Y) Length of each line as to match if should first match the length.
- Sorting the array will add complexity to it. So better to avoid it.